# DAX PowerBI: Replaced blank values with zero and issue with chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

I tried to create report in Power BI with sales month by month for last 20 months, when sales is blank I want to see month with 0 value.

I decided to change Blank() values with zero adding a 0 at the end of calculation.

It works great, however I have an issue with limitaton date hierarchy, because now my chart contains a lot of months without value (first value begins in 2017, date hierarchy first value begins in 2000).

```
Test:=
  CALCULATE (
    SUM( quantity ),
    flag = 1, 
    title = "WEEKS"
   ) + 0
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a filter on date to your visual?

Comment: Yes, I tried add filter in report and I tried add filter in measure- I still see all periods.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the situation? I don't think that should be happening.

Comment: It can happen when you have 2 tables, your data table and your value table. Have you considered using an IF statement?

Comment: Why not just remove rows from your date dimension before 2017?

Comment: I need to use Live Connection

Comment: Here is how it looks (and problem is that I need to show only last 20 months, not all months from Date table): https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vrg0fr5nvl6v9r/zero%20values.JPG?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a plain `0`, you could add an `IF` to specify to only add that after the first value. Something like this:

```
Test:=
VAR FirstDate = CALCULATE ( MIN ( date ), ALL( Dates ), quantity > 0 )
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    SUM( quantity ),
    flag = 1, 
    title = "WEEKS"
   ) + IF( date > FirstDate, 0 )
```

If the condition is false, the `IF` returns a blank and it shouldn't show up.